# How to calculate total sales done by Sales Rep to make Sales Rep Score Card?

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure what is the total sales done by a particular sales rep to make sales rep score card. I have the data from 5 tables. I was able to create a query that selects all the necessary data required.

```
Query:
SELECT OrderLine.OrderID, OrderLine.ProductID, OrderLine.TotalCostPrice, 
OrderLine.TotalSellPrice, OrderLine.BranchID, OrderLine.TotalMargin, 
OrderPayment.PaymentDateTime, CreditNoteHeader.TakenByID, Branch.Name, 
Branch.BranchCode, OrderPayment.UserID,
SalesRep.Name AS SName, SalesRep.SalesRepID, SalesRep.SalesRepCode 
From OrderLine Inner Join OrderPayment on OrderLine.OrderID=OrderPayment.OrderID 
Left Outer Join CreditNoteHeader on OrderLine.OrderID= CreditNoteHeader.OrderID
Left Outer Join Branch on OrderLine.BranchID=Branch.BranchID
Left Outer Join SalesRep on OrderPayment.UserID=SalesRep.UserID;
```

This comes up with the table that displays OrderID, ProductID, TotalCostPrice, TotalSellPrice, BranchID, TotalMargin, PaymentDateTime, TakenByID, BranchName, BranchCode, UserID, RepName, SalesRepID, SalesRepCode. I am not sure where to go from here. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: By using SUM() and GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Common Table Expressions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cte-in-sql/) to perform query on the result of query that you have created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use then `SUM()` with `GROUP BY` `SName, SalesRepID, SalesRepCode` like below

```
WITH cte_TempTable AS (
    SELECT ol.OrderID, ol.ProductID, ol.TotalCostPrice, 
    ol.TotalSellPrice, ol.BranchID, ol.TotalMargin, 
    op.PaymentDateTime, cnh.TakenByID, b.Name, 
    b.BranchCode, op.UserID,
    sr.Name AS SName, sr.SalesRepID, sr.SalesRepCode 

    From OrderLine ol
    Inner Join OrderPayment op on ol.OrderID = op.OrderID 
    Left Outer Join CreditNoteHeader cnh on ol.OrderID= cnh.OrderID
    Left Outer Join Branch b on ol.bID=b.BranchID
    Left Outer Join SalesRep sr on op.UserID=sr.UserID
    -- Where your_condition_here
)
SELECT SUM(TotalCostPrice) TotalCostPrice, SUM(TotalSellPrice) TotalSellPrice, SName, SalesRepID, SalesRepCode 
FROM cte_TempTable
GROUP BY SName, SalesRepID, SalesRepCode
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Anchal

Answer (score 0):

You can just add your Query in a braces and consider its result as a temporary table and apply grouping  on salesman fields and then do sum on other fields you want to get the aggregate

```
SELECT        SName, SalesRepID, SalesRepCode, SUM(TotalCostPrice) AS TotalCostPrice, SUM(TotalSellPrice) AS TotalSellPrice, SUM(TotalMargin) AS TotalMargin
FROM            (SELECT        OrderLine.OrderID, OrderLine.ProductID, OrderLine.TotalCostPrice, OrderLine.TotalSellPrice, OrderLine.BranchID, OrderLine.TotalMargin, OrderPayment.PaymentDateTime, CreditNoteHeader.TakenByID, 
                                                    Branch.Name, Branch.BranchCode, OrderPayment.UserID, SalesRep.Name AS SName, SalesRep.SalesRepID, SalesRep.SalesRepCode
                          FROM            OrderLine INNER JOIN
                                                    OrderPayment ON OrderLine.OrderID = OrderPayment.OrderID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    CreditNoteHeader ON OrderLine.OrderID = CreditNoteHeader.OrderID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    Branch ON OrderLine.BranchID = Branch.BranchID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                                    SalesRep ON OrderPayment.UserID = SalesRep.UserID) AS templtable
GROUP BY SName, SalesRepID, SalesRepCode
```